# Closure Compiler: ERROR - cannot read

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I downloaded Google Closure Compiler from official Google website (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app). And then run it to minify my widget.js but i received the error below:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\compiler-latest>java -jar
>   compiler.jar --js "wi dget.js" \ --js_output_file "output.js" ERROR -
>   Cannot read: \
>
> 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

[image]

I tried to change my widget.js content, if the widget.js contain some syntax error it will tell me know. But it seem that the "error - CANNOT READ \" always show up even my widget.js is empty or just have a line alert('test');

How can i resolve that error?

Comment: What does it say if you remove that \ that is between `'widget.js'` and --`js_output_file`?

Comment: On a side note, there is another tool [called plovr](http://plovr.com/) that makes using closure compiler easier.

Answer (score -1):

You should run your compiler as following:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js widget.js --js_output_file output.js
```

You can put multi js files and seperate by a space without double quote ("), single quote (') or slash (/) like your case.

Hope this help.